# Adding up individual filesizes in a youtube playlist to get total filesize value

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, youtube-dl

I can get the **filesizes** of each file in a youtube playlist but **how can I add all the individual filesizes together to get a total size in Megabytes or Gigabytes of all of them added together**?

Example: Linux / Ubuntu commands

```
youtube-dl --get-filename -o "File size for %(id)s (%(format_id)s): %(filesize)s = 125*%(duration)s*%(tbr)s" -f "22/best" --ignore-config  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b26ZBgspv7M&list=PLLYQF5WvJdJXE-aP7oF5ucXcCfHmub34A" | (IFS='='; while read -r a b; do echo "$a = $(echo "$b" | bc)"; done)
```

- 

```
File size for b26ZBgspv7M (22): NA  = 632016.000
File size for nPr3qtZ5FVE (18): NA  = 47577837.000
File size for 8FCsS6s1Z0k (18): NA  = 67788616.500
File size for TZANoOWFX1M (18): 62402644  = 62393587.750
File size for XA5eobevGv8 (22): NA  = 117960449.500
File size for lDplUpPoCcI (22): NA  = 175676293.75
File size for a7TUIkn3qjY (22): NA  = 299391049.125
File size for HFPObieGamg (22): NA  = 270756696.875
File size for PiiDs8dzSXk (22): NA  = 55946363.250
File size for tth0p7nK18A (22): NA  = 31281180.00
File size for Z_xj9ZTV8ak (22): NA  = 126366879.000
File size for Y_YHqM5nTHA (22): NA  = 42328527.000
File size for BjV-fRCPgAM (22): NA  = 42225633.375
```

Comment: Just `echo "$a = $(echo "$b" | bc)"` -> `sum=$(echo "$sum + $b" | bc)`...

Comment: Duplicate of [Youtube-dl playlist and calculating how big the files are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70226779/youtube-dl-playlist-and-calculating-how-big-the-files-are)

Comment: No, it's not the same question.  This one was dealing with getting the total of all the file sizes.   Luckily, people have helped and answered the questions.....(And I posted the answers that have helped back to stackoverflow to share).... I'm not sure why people want it closed / down voting it clearly deals with scripting and the categories offered....Very Strange...Maybe it's youtube people upset with youtube-dl ;-)

Comment: I've retracted my duplicate vote - I'll take your word that it isn't quite the same. I think both are only borderline suitable for the site. The questions appear to be just using youtube-dl as a tool, which isn't really about programming. I realize the answers do get into shell scripting though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aready seem to know how to split input - just sum it then.

```
youtube-dl ..... | (
   sum=0
   while IFS='=' read -r a b; do
       sum=$(echo "$sum + $b" | bc)
   done
   echo "The sum: $sum"
)
```

Interest yourself in `awk`, it's a real handy tool. You can search "how to sum column in awk" for sure you'll get ton of examples.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost done it:

```
youtube-dl ...args...  |
{ while IFS='=' read -r a b; do printf '%s + ' "$b"; done; echo 0; }  | bc
```

or using `cut` and `tr`:

```
youtube-dl ...args...  |
{ cut -d= -f2 | tr '\n' +; echo 0; } | bc
```

or using `sed`

```
youtube-dl ...args...  |
sed 's/.*=//;H;$!d;g;s/.//;s/\n/+/g' | bc
```

Answer (score 1):

Compose the whole arithmetic to feed to `bc`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "125*(0$(youtube-dl --get-filename -o "+(%(duration)s*%(tbr)s)" -f "22/best" --ignore-config  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b26ZBgspv7M&list=PLLYQF5WvJdJXE-aP7oF5ucXcCfHmub34A"))" |
{ tr -d '\n'; echo;} |
bc -l
```

First it prints `125*(0`
Then `youtube-dl` prints a successions of `+(duration*tbr)` followed by a newline,
then add a trailing `)`
resulting in something like:

```
125*(0+(duration*tbr)
+(duration*tbr)
+(duration*tbr)
)
```

To turn it into a valid `bc` computation syntax, newlines need be discarded with `tr -d '\n'`, and a final newline added with `echo`

Answer (score 0):

Includes the individual filesizes with the sum at the end.

```
youtube-dl --get-filename -o "File size for %(id)s (%(format_id)s): %(filesize)s = 125*%(duration)s*%(tbr)s" -f "22/best" --ignore-config  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b26ZBgspv7M&list=PLLYQF5WvJdJXE-aP7oF5ucXcCfHmub34A" | (
       sum=0
       while IFS='=' read -r a b; do
           echo "$a = $(echo "$b" | bc)"
           sum=$(echo "$sum + $b" | bc)
       done
       echo "The sum: $sum"
    )
```

Output:

```
File size for b26ZBgspv7M (22): NA  = 632016.000
File size for nPr3qtZ5FVE (18): NA  = 47577837.000
File size for 8FCsS6s1Z0k (18): NA  = 67788616.500
File size for TZANoOWFX1M (18): 62402644  = 62393587.750
File size for XA5eobevGv8 (22): NA  = 117960449.500
File size for lDplUpPoCcI (22): NA  = 175676293.75
File size for a7TUIkn3qjY (22): NA  = 299391049.125
File size for HFPObieGamg (22): NA  = 270756696.875
File size for PiiDs8dzSXk (22): NA  = 55946363.250
File size for tth0p7nK18A (22): NA  = 31281180.00
File size for Z_xj9ZTV8ak (22): NA  = 126366879.000
File size for Y_YHqM5nTHA (22): NA  = 42328527.000
File size for BjV-fRCPgAM (22): NA  = 42225633.375
The sum: 1340325129.125
```